# How to differentiate between lambda and def functions?

Tags: python, function

Is there way to do a type comparison for lambdas and def functions? I expect `False` to be output via some procedure, but I don't know if that level of granularity is native to python functions. My use case is making sure that a function registered to an event is not a lambda so it can be unregisterable later via another method.

```
def foo():
    pass

(lambda: None).__class__ == foo.__class__ # >> True
```

Edit: my use case is actually more educational than functional, so I'm really just concerned with ways of distinguishing lambda functions from def functions.

Comment: Honestly, this should not be your concern.  When and if the user tries to unregister, they will realize their mistake.  I should be able to use a lambda if I want to.

Comment: People can absolutely unregister lambdas, as long as they store them. And someone can make a function defined with `def` that can't be unregistered easily, if they throw away the reference to its name. So I have to agree -- don't try to enforce this. It's innately futile, and restrains the flexibility of the folks using your library to design their code how they like.

Comment: Can you explain your use case more?  It sounds like you want to require the caller to keep a reference to the function they pass.  There's no _real_ way to do that and even if they pass you a function that was defined with a lambda expression, they may very well continue to have a reference to it.  Consider `f = lambda x: x` compared to `def f(x): ...` followed by `del f`.

Comment: "My use case is making sure that a function registered to an event is not a lambda so it can be unregisterable later via another method." That really doesn't make much sense. In any case, the answer to "Is there way to do a type comparison for lambdas and def functions" Is "no, lambda expressions and function definition statements create objects of the exact same type". You can introspect things like the `.name` attribute that could help you distinguish between them, but again, I'm still skeptical about the need or soundness

Comment: @KyleParsons or for that matter, a function could be defined in some local scope, and they actually have no other reference to it! This distinction isn't really sound.

Comment: ...if you really want to force things to be unregisterable, it would make more sense to have the call to register accept a handle or name that can be passed to the unregister call in place of the original object itself.

Comment: (having a registry with keys also allows operations like "list all the registered handlers" to let one see which handlers are active, and optionally reuse keys from that list to unregister a subset should one so choose, so it's useful for more reasons than just this one).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the function's name. A lambda will be named `<lambda>`.

```
def islambda(f):
    return f.__name__ == '<lambda>'

def foo():
    pass

print(islambda(lambda: None)) # True
print(islambda(foo)) # false
```

Comment: Would `__qualname__` be more or less reliable?

Comment: @Locke No difference. We don't care what the actual name is if it's a named function, we just care if it's `<lambda>` or not.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there was any chance of `__name__` being reset by accident due to decorators or some other edge case.

Comment: Unless you can decorate a lambda and it gets a different name, I don't think it's a concern.

Comment: @Locke I mean, it definitely *could*. There probably is no very reliable way to distinguish between function objects created with lambda expressions and those created with function definition statements, if someone is determined to obscure it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga His use case sounds like a sanity check. In that context, if someone deliberately tries to fool it, it's their own problem.

Comment: @Barmar sure, although I disagree that it is a useful sanity check. Anonymous function doesn't mean unreferenced function, and functions created with a definition statement won't necessarily have any other references sticking around.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Those exceptions sound like "deliberately trying to fool it".

Comment: I think it might be appropriate to use `islambda = lambda f: f.__name__ == '<lambda>'` here so `islambda(islambda)` → `True` — although unregistering it could be difficult… `;¬)`

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas can be identified by their `__name__` field, whose value will initially be `<lambda>`, whereas a `def` function will have its real name in this field.

```
def foo():
    pass

bar = lambda: None

print(foo.__name__) # foo
print(bar.__name__) # bar
```

But, do note that I can "trick" this. There's nothing stopping me from giving a lambda a name.

```
baz = lambda: None
baz.__name__ = "Hah! Gotcha!"

print(baz.__name__) # Hah! Gotcha!
```

Comment: Conversely, there's nothing stopping you from assigning a lambda to a variable: `bar = lambda: None`